# Facebook app request notification in Android leading to app page instead of launching

Tags: android, facebook

I'm experiencing the following flow in my game over Android, with facebook integration:

1. User A sends an apprequest with some data to user B.
2. User B receives a notification about that request from the facebook app.
3. User B clicks the notification,
4. User B's facebook app opens up with the app page.
5. User B has to click

   - In Candy Crush Saga, the app is launched automatically.
   - In our app we see the app page as written in (4) above

Any ideas how to make it launch the game instead of showing the app page?

Thanks

Comment: How did you solve this issue I got stuck on the same , can you help me with debugging the problem I am also getting redirected to my website instead of installed app

Comment: Didn't manage to solve it, if you do please share your findings.